# 20.04 problem updating/installing from local repository error 404 not found, no installation candidate found

Tags: apt, server, repository

I've successfully created a local repository on a 20.04 server VM. However, I'm not able to perform installs or updates from that repository. Attached is a screenshot that shows the results of an update as well as the sources.list contents and a web browser pointing to the repository contents.
Multiple errors indicate 404 not found which is appropriate for the file icons-64x64@2.rar because it wasn't found in the repository in the expected location. When attempting to install packages, the message "E: Package 'packagename' has no installation candidate" is returned.
This pic was taken from a 20.04 desktop VM with address 192.168.46.129.The repository host name is "repo" which resolves to address 192.168.46.130
This configuration has been attempted multiple times in multiple environments with the same results. For example, a 20.04 server VM from a fresh snapshot was used and the results were the same as the original attempt. A second VMware environment was used to host a 20.04 server and 20.04 desktop VMs and the results were the same.
In both environments, neither server or desktop VMs were able to successfully use the local repository. Yes, you read that correctly - the server wasn't able to  utilize the repository that it was hosting locally.
Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.
[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoCqX.png)

Answer (score 0):

**A problem exists with the version of apt-mirror that ships with Ubuntu 20.04.**
Per the following github issues, it causes apt updates to fail when local  repositories are used.
https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/102
https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/118

Here's a link to the updated apt-mirror package I used to solve this problem.
https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror